# Bootstrap table without lines not working with custom css class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET MVC Core app, I'm using Bootstrap table class that always shows horizontal lines after each row. So, I added following class to the default `site.css` file - of the Visual Studio project - to get rid of theses lines. But the horizontal lines are still showing up even though as you can see below the site.css file was loaded. Moreover, as expected and as shown below, after I added following custom class to site.css it showed up in the intellisense as `table-borderless` in `<table class="table table-borderless table-condensed table-hover">` that means Visual Studio does recognize the custom class I added to site.css.

**Custom class added to site.css**:

```
...other classes here...
....
.table-borderless td,
.table-borderless th {
    border: 0;
}
```

**test.cshtml**:

```
...other html tags here...
...
<table class="table table-borderless table-condensed table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Source View of test.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
--some other content here....
....
<table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
    <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                row 1 cell 1 
            </td>
            <td>
                row 1 cell 2            
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                row 2 cell 1
            </td>
            <td>
                row 2 cell 2           
            </td>
        </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:

Following are the snapshots of the page in Google Chrome when I inspect a table row:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: when you inspect the element in chrome, or equiv. browser, what styles are applied to the table?

Comment: @JanR I've just added an UPDATE to my post with a snapshot of what you are probably asking.

Comment: Can you add `!important` to your `border:0` style? I think the weighting of the CSS tags from bootstrap are overriding your change as they are considered more important

Comment: @JanR I tried your suggestion of adding `!important`. But no effect. Please also see my comment to Paul's reply below if that can help.

Comment: in the list on the right of your screenshot, can you see your styles at all? even with a strike-through?

Comment: @JanR Yes. I've added two more snapshots.

Comment: It doesn't seem to show your `.table-borderless` class at all, are you sure your css is included?

Comment: @JanR My bad. I have replaced the third image with a new one and circled the `.table-borderless` part in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is "winning" from bootstrap.css:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

Your CSS selectors are less specific so they are being ignored.  Try

```
.table-borderless > tbody > tr > td,
.table-borderless > thead > tr > th {
    border: 0;
}
```

Also, add `<thead>` to match `<tbody>`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (added thead as well) but still no effect. It seems my scenario may be a bit more complex since I am using [ViewComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) (introduced in MVC6) and the table is inside that Viewcomponent (like a partial view in legacy MVC)